# PHP type hinting and inheritance

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I have a bunch of DB models that all extend a base class called `myDBModel`, something like:

```
class myPostgresModel extends myDBModel
```

I am building a group of classes that interact with these models, and they all extend another base class called `MyBaseParser`. These parser classes need to take a DB model as a parameter but it could be any of the available models. So I defined it like

```
class myBaseParser implements ParserInterface
{
    public function doSomething(myDBModel $model){}
}

interface ParserInterface
{
    public function doSomething(myDBModel $model);
}
```

then

```
class myPostgresParser
{ 
    public function doSomething(myPostgresModel $model) {}
```

If I create a postgres parser, and pass in the `myPostgresModel` into the `doSomething` method, I get an error since it's expecting `myDBModel`. Shouldn't the `myPostgresModel` be accepted since it's a child of the `myDBModel` class? What's the right way to handle this inheritance?

Comment: Can you provide an actual replication case? This should be possible to replicate in the likes of 3v4l.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've shared shouldn't throw any error, possibly because you forgot to make `myPostgresParser` inherit some `myBaseParser` or implement `ParserInterface`. My guess is that you want this:

```
class myPostgresParser extends myBaseParser {}
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In any case there's an underlying design problem. You want to pretend that `myPostgresParser` implements `ParserInterface::doSomething()` but actually implement a different method with the same name but (slightly) different arguments. PHP should warn about that with a message like:

> Fatal error: Declaration of myPostgresParser::doSomething(myPostgresModel $model) must be compatible with ParserInterface::doSomething(myDBModel $model)

*(If you can't see error messages, make sure you've configured your dev environment to display them.)*

The error message is of course correct: if `myPostgresParser::doSomething()` cannot do the job with any class that inherits from `myDBModel` then it isn't compliant with the interface, neither does it make much sense to define an interface in the first place.

I suggest you get back to the design table and decide what role `myDBModel` plays here. Models should have some normalised behaviours across engines on which third-party classes could rely.